# “I make a hundred k a year”

Tags: abbreviations, numbers

> I make a hundred k a year.

How much money does someone earn when he says the above? I understand it as

- *make = earn*
- *hundred = 100*
- *k = kilo*

With this the sentence translates to:

> I earn 100000 CUR a year.

where *CUR* is an undefined currency which seems to be known by all parties.

Is that correct? If not, why not?

Comment: The symbol K is sometimes used for a thousand, for example in referring to units of salary or in reference to the Y2K computer bug. 

The letter "K" is used to represent 1000, because it represents the prefix "kilo," which means 1000 of something in the metric system. For instance, kilogram means 1000 grams.

Comment: Yes, k is commonly used to mean "thousand", as it was traditionally done in kilogram and kilometre as well.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In America, it'd be a hundred thousand dollars.

Comment: I've also heard the term "kilo-bucks".  First heard terminology this ca 1970.

Comment: Funnily enough in The Netherlands, 100,000 is called a Ton(ne)

Comment: @mplungjan Well that's just ridiculously silly and uninternational.

Comment: @mplungjan: that is indeed hard to understand internationally, but it stems from the fact that the Dutch Guilder used to weig 10 grams, meaning 100,000 Guilders weighed 1,000 kilo, which is a ton. A more commonly used factor of 100,000 is the Indian **lakh** (and they have the _crore_ which is 10 million).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. K is short for kilo. 1K is one thousand, as in:

- Kilometer: 1000 meters
- Kilogram: 1000 grams
- Kilobyte: 1000 bytes (actually 1024)

To say that you earn 100K means that you earn 100,000.

Answer (score 0):

100K is also very commonly used in ASIA as well. Here 1K normally means 1000 (local currency).

'Kg' is also a symbol for kilo, which contains 1000 grams. So K can be informally used to say a thousand and nowadays it is very common informal practice in Asia as well.

"I make a hundred k a year" means he is earning a hundred thousand (local currency) a year.

Comment: Actually "kilo" is the SI prefix for one thousand of _any_ unit. It's just that "Kilogram" ("Kg") is often informally abbreviated to "kilo".